# How to write a multiple Aync Function within a Service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im just starting on AngularJS.  I'm not sure how to churn this out.  I'm trying to include multiple functions within one service. (I hope this is not against bad practice.)

The following is my working code:

```
myDataService.async().then(function (d) {            
         $scope.dbCalls = d.d;            
    });
```

My Service:

```
app.factory('myDataService', function ($http) {
// How do you get this bottom line to work?
// this.getAllCalls = function () {
    var myService = {
        async: function () {                
            var promise = $http.post('AngularTest.aspx/FetchCalls', { data: {} }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return myService;
//};  <--Commented out for clarity
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just return an object with properties from the service, then you are able to call those properties as different service methods

like so:

```
.service('myService', function() {
    return {
        firstMethod: function() { ... },
        secondMethod: function() { ... },
        thirdMethod: function() { ... }
    }
})
```

and in the controller/directive

```
.controller('myCtrl', function(myService) {
    myService.firstMethod();
    myService.secondMethod();
    myService.thirdMethod();
})
```